# apache IndexOptions not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost, raspbian

Can anyone tell me what I've missed?  I can't get the IndexOptions directive to work.  I have included my virtual host *.conf file.  I've done this before, with an almost identical virtual host settings file and it worked fine.  However, in the past I have used ubuntu server and this time I am using debian-raspbian-lite with apache2 installed.  My server address is http://c64stuff.ddns.net.

Virtual host config:
http://c64stuff.ddns.net/vhost-config.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  It was a typo.  (c64tuff)